# Android Version Upgradation

Tags: updates

I have an Android Version `4.04` ICS on my Samsung Galaxy S Duos phone, how do I upgrade to version `4.1` as I am aware it is possible, did try to `Google`, but in vain as I did not find satisfactory answers. Is it possible to use the Debugging Mode to upgrade the version.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can update using kies if samsung has released official update for your phone.
If there is no official update, search for custom roms. Installation instructions will be found along with such roms. Use your best judgement.

This question seems to be off-topic btw. Please go through the rules.